# Unable to install latest ejabberd and Erlang version Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: makefile, erlang, ubuntu-14.04, ejabberd, erlang-shell

Currently I have Erlang version 5.10.4 and OTP "R16B03". 
Now I have to update Erlang from version 6.1 and OTP greater than 17.1 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bit) in order to install the latest version of ejabberd (16.02).

For this I have tried instructions at this URL: http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html 
but when I am hitting the make command an error is coming:-

```
Makefile:247: /home/Hemant/otp_src_18.2/make/i686-pc-linux-gnu/otp_ded.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/Hemant/otp_src_18.2/make/i686-pc-linux-gnu/otp_ded.mk'.  Stop.
```

I tried another way:

```
$ sudo apt-get install erlang
```

But I am getting the same version (Erlang 5.10) while I have updated the apt-get.

Now how can I get the latest version of Erlang?

Comment: You could try downloading a pre-built version for your platform from https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html .

Comment: I always download Erlang source code from erlang.org and build it myself.

Answer (score 5):

When installing erlang do the following from this [link](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html):

```
wget http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
```

Now the repository is added simply install esl-erlang with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install esl-erlang
```

Installing ejabberd follow Mickaël's [blog](https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-joins-the-elixir-revolution/) post:

```
git clone git@github.com:processone/ejabberd.git
cd ejabberd
chmod +x autogen.sh
./autogen.sh
./configure
sudo make && make install
```

Now I do remember getting quite a few compiler errors and all the errors were due to packages not being installed on my system. So when you receive an error from say libexpat then install the package `sudo apt-get install libexpat1` and so on for all the following errors.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As your question is more on ejabberd than Erlang itself, you can download ejabberd prepackaged with its own Erlang version from ProcessOne site: https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads

If you want to learn about alternative ways to install ejabberd, you can follow the official documentation: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/

You can for example see at bottom of the page instructions to build ejabberd from source if you prefer.

Comment: Hi Mickael, I have download the ejabberd_16.02-0_amd64.deb from https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads and when i am running this than it's asking for Erlang. I tried another way and download the source code, But when i hit make command it is also ask for Erlang. Please tell me how can i download prepackaged code. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, asking for Erlang ? Erlang is including in the package. You should be able to start ejabberd with ejabberdctl out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to check the file in your error but I don't see it in the sources: https://github.com/erlang/otp/tree/OTP-18.2.4/make Can you try to clone it directly from GitHub and then compile? Or...

I recommend you to download Erlang packages specifically precompiled for Ubuntu from Erlang Solutions: https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html

I was using them whenever I had to install Erlang on Ubuntu and never had problems. The codename for your Ubuntu would be Trusty Tahr.